# Audio loudness normalization using ffmpeg decreases the duration of audio files?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm using the following code to normalize the audio loudness but after running the code the length/duration of the audio is decreased ...I don't know where I have to make the changes..can anyone help me for this....if possible please explain the code also....I'm new to this and I have no idea about tha's why..

```
def r128Stats(filePath):

ffargs = ['ffmpeg',
          '-nostats',
          '-i',
          filePath,
          '-filter_complex',
          'ebur128',
          '-f',
          'null',
          '-']

proc = subprocess.Popen(ffargs, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stats = proc.communicate()[1]
summaryIndex = stats.rfind('Summary:'.encode())
summaryList = stats[summaryIndex:].split()
ILufs = float(summaryList[summaryList.index('I:'.encode()) + 1])
IThresh = float(summaryList[summaryList.index('I:'.encode()) + 4])
LRA = float(summaryList[summaryList.index('LRA:'.encode()) + 1])
LRAThresh = float(summaryList[summaryList.index('LRA:'.encode()) + 4])
LRALow = float(summaryList[summaryList.index('low:'.encode()) + 1])
LRAHigh = float(summaryList[summaryList.index('high:'.encode()) + 1])
statsDict = {'I': ILufs, 'I Threshold': IThresh, 'LRA': LRA,
             'LRA Threshold': LRAThresh, 'LRA Low': LRALow,
             'LRA High': LRAHigh}
return statsDict

def linearGain(iLUFS, goalLUFS=-23):
""" takes a floating point value for iLUFS, returns the necessary
multiplier for audio gain to get to the goalLUFS value """
gainLog = -(iLUFS - goalLUFS)
return 10 ** (gainLog / 20)


def ffApplyGain(inPath, outPath, linearAmount):

ffargs = ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', inPath,
          '-af', 'volume=' + str(linearAmount)]
if outPath[-10:].lower() == '.mp3':
    ffargs += ['-acodec', 'libmp3lame', '-aq', '0']
ffargs += [outPath]
subprocess.Popen(ffargs, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


def notAudio(filePath):
if os.path.basename(filePath).startswith("audio"):
    return True
thisMime = mimetypes.guess_type(re.escape(filePath))[0]
if thisMime is None or not thisMime.startswith("audio"):
    return True
return False


def neg23File(filePath):
if notAudio(filePath):
    print("Not a valid audio file.")
    return False
print("Scanning " + filePath + " for loudness...")
try:
    loudnessStats = r128Stats(filePath)
except:
    print("neg23 encountered an error scanning " + filePath)
gainAmount = linearGain(loudnessStats['I'])
print("Creating -23LUFS file at " + filePath)
try:
    # applying the normalisation and saving it to the same place as it was (replacing)
    ffApplyGain(filePath, filePath, gainAmount)
except:
    print("neg23 encountered an error applying gain to " + filePath)
print("Done")


def normalise(args):
source = os.path.abspath(args.source)
results = {"Successfully normalised": 0, "Unsuccessful": 0}

for filename in glob.glob(source + '/**/*.wav', recursive=True):
    try:
        neg23File(filename)
        results["Successfully normalised"] += 1
    except:
        results["Unsuccessful"] += 1           

print("\n")
print(results)
```

Comment: Do you still need help with this, or have you figured it out?

Comment: Why would you not use the loudnorm method to perform true normalization for the file since you've already captured the information you need to perform normalization? Adjusting the volume is not true normalization.  Am I missing something?  Would the ffmpeg-normalize utility be what you're looking for?

Comment: Another issue I see with this is in your call to ffApplyGain.  You are overwriting the source file.  From what I've read, this can cause bad things.  It is suggested you write the file to another location (temp folder maybe?) and then overwrite the source file after it has been output by ffmpeg.